# Why does module parse failed: /xxx/MyFont.ttf Unexpected character ''

Tags: webpack, less, font-face, urlloader

I encountered this error

> ERROR in ./src/style/MyFont.ttf Module parse failed: /xxx/MyFont.ttf
>   Unexpected character '' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to
>   handle this file type. (Source code omitted for this binary file)`
>   when I import my custom font in my less file like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "MyFont";
    src: url("./MyFont.ttf") format("truetype"); 
}
```

my webpack config is as follow:

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    query: babelQuery
  },{
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader'
    ]
  },
  {
    test: /\.less$/i,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract([ 'css-loader', 'less-loader' ])
  },
  { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
]
```

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Seems that you don't include the webpack plugin for the `.ttf`. :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `rules` array.

```
{
  test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
  loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
}
```

and you should install the `file-loader` using `npm install`.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: yes, but seems you don't use any loaders.
replace it my code.
I think, that will work :)

Comment: that's url loader i am using... Tried your solution, it didnt work

Comment: what is your web pack version?